# get bash-style command cycling with clink

Tags: cmd.exe, clink

With bash, even without changes to the .bashrc, I can write the beginning of a command (e.g. "gr"), and press the up key to cycle through commands with this perfix (e.g. "grep -R asdf .").

With clink, cycling up commands ignores the command prefix I had already written. 
I know I can use Ctrl+r to match a regex with a full command, but that isn't as coinvent.

Comment: If it is bash why tag it CMD.exe.  In CMD press `gr` then F8 cycles.

Comment: it's clink - a bash for Windows